# Add files to project in CMakefile

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the instructions, it is not clear how I edit the CMakefile.txt to add files to the project (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace)

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src

# Add/Edit source files

$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials

# Update CMakeFiles.txt to reflect any changes to your sources

$ cd ~/catkin_ws

$ catkin_make
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93231/add-files-to-project-in-cmakefile/) by [dimonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7996/dimonic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to be more specific. What files do you want to add? If it's a library that your code depend on then,

```
add_library(SOURCE_LIB src/some_lib_source.c)
target_link_libraries(SOURCE_LIB ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

now you can add SOURCE_LIB to link it with your code

```
target_link_libraries(your_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} SOURCE_LIB)
```

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dimonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7996/dimonic/) on 2013-10-23**:
Actually your answer illustrates part of the problem. I wanted to add another source file, but I assume the instructions would differ depending on the type of file that one wanted to add.

Perahps that guide is assuming a level of understanding of cmake that is not "beginner"?

BTW - I assumed (C++ programmer background) that a source file is source code, as in a cpp file.

For now I am ignoring the packaging stuff and moving on with example_node, assuming that clarity will emerge later.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-10-23**:
Yes, it would help if you had just a bit more of cmake understanding, such as by doing this tutorial ([http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/~adanner/tips/cmake.php](http://web.cs.swarthmore.edu/%7Eadanner/tips/cmake.php)). Some explanations also here: (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt)

**Comment by [dimonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7996/dimonic/) on 2013-10-23**:
And then there is the confusion caused by some tutorial examples using catkin and others using some other build technique (publisher subscriber with dynamic reconfigure example). Am I right in assuming that catkin is the way forward ?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-23**:
@dimonic I would recommend using catkin, though it has a steeper learning curve than the old system (rosbuild) I think it would serve you best to learn that. Can you post a link to the tutorial that is out of date?

**Comment by [dimonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/7996/dimonic/) on 2013-10-23**:
Thank you, I will use catkin going forward. The tutorial using rosbuild is here http://wiki.ros.org/ROSNodeTutorialC%2B%2B (at least I think it uses rosbuild - it lacks a package.xml file).